# Wait for one plugin to finish registering, before proceeding to register the next one

Tags: node.js, fastify

How can I wait for one plugin to finish registering, before proceeding to register the next one?

I wish to initialize the connection to the database using credentials that are retrieved from a `.env` file using the plugin `fastify-env`.

Fastify proceeds to register the `fastify-sequelize`-plugin **before the environment variables are loaded**. This leads to the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'DB_NAME' of undefined`.

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const AutoLoad = require('fastify-autoload')
const fastifyEnv = require('fastify-env')
const fsequelize = require('fastify-sequelize')

module.exports = function (fastify, opts, next) {
  fastify
    .register(fastifyEnv, {
      schema: {
        type: 'object',
        required: [ 'PORT', 'NODE_ENV', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD' ],
        properties: {
          PORT: { type: 'integer' },
          NODE_ENV: { type: 'string' },
          DB_NAME: { type: 'string' },
          DB_USERNAME: { type: 'string' },
          DB_PASSWORD: { type: 'string' }
        }
      },
      dotenv: true
    }).ready((err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)
      console.log("config ready=",fastify.config) // This works!
    })

  fastify.register(fsequelize, {
      instance: 'sequelize',
      autoConnect: true,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      database: fastify.config.DB_NAME,
      username: fastify.config.DB_USERNAME,
      password: fastify.config.DB_PASSWORD
  })
  fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
    options: Object.assign({}, opts)
  })

  fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'services'),
    options: Object.assign({}, opts)
  })


  next()
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the easiest workaround was to simply put my credentials in a .js-file and require it. (Skipping the use of dotenv or fastifyEnv alltogether)

Answer (score 1):

Fastify registers plugins and middleware in the same way, synchronous and one after another in the order in which they are registered.  It should not be requiring these modules asynchronously.

However, there are many different before and after handlers you can tap into for each plugin.

https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Lifecycle.md

Answer (score 1):

Your script should work, I think the problem is caused by something else.

Anyway you can use the `.after` API after the `.register`:

```
const Fastify = require('fastify')
const fastify = Fastify({ logger: false })

fastify.register((instance, opts, next) => {
  console.log('one')
  setTimeout(next, 1000)
}).after(() => {
  fastify.register((instance, opts, next) => {
    console.log('two')
    setTimeout(next, 1000)
  })
  fastify.register((instance, opts, next) => {
    console.log('three')
    next()
  })
})

fastify.register((instance, opts, next) => {
  console.log('four')
  next()
})

fastify.listen(3000)
```

Will print:

> one
>
> two
>
> three
>
> four